# Export my asp.net MVC model data into Excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following 5 models inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
 public partial class Anwer
    {
        public Anwer()
        {
            this.UserFormsAnswers = new HashSet<UserFormsAnswer>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AnwerDesc { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public bool Correct { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserFormsAnswer> UserFormsAnswers { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.Anwers = new HashSet<Anwer>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDesc { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Anwer> Anwers { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class UserFormsAnswer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }
        public int FormID { get; set; }

        public virtual Anwer Anwer { get; set; }
        public virtual UsersForm UsersForm { get; set; }
    }
   public partial class UsersForm
    {
        public UsersForm()
        {
            this.UserFormsAnswers = new HashSet<UserFormsAnswer>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTimeOffset DateSubmitted { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserFormsAnswer> UserFormsAnswers { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            this.UsersForms = new HashSet<UsersForm>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UsersForm> UsersForms { get; set; }
    }
```

in short i have a UserForms which store an exam info, and the UserFormsAnswer is the actula answers for each exam. and i have questions and answers.

now i am trying to export the following values into excel sheet:-

```
user name | Question1 ID | Question2 ID | Question3 ID | ....
UserA     | True         | False        | True         |.....
UserB     | True         | True         | True         |.....
```

so can anyone adivce how i can group my data as shown above and then export the data into an excel sheet for the user to download and read?

Comment: How many questions you have to display results with? It is hard (and probably inefficient) way to generate viewmodel for them dynamically, hence you need to define collections of users & their question results in a viewmodel & export the data from it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i do not have a specific number of questions.. they can be 20 or 30 or less...and i have around 60 users.. but for me this appraoch is acceptable.. but i am facing problems in understanding how i can group my data and generate the excel  accordingly ..

Comment: With that setup, perhaps you want to define expected fixed maximum number of questions where the collection can handle them. Then in theory you can export the collection to Excel file depending number of available questions (which question column results are not entirely null/empty).